# Pandas Dataframe: Split a single column into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to split a column `Class` into multiple columns and change column names based on that.

```
    ID    Name    Class       

  0    12    John      A
  1    13    Mark      A
  2    14    Tony      B
  3    15    Marcus    C 
  4    16    Phill     D
  5    17    Jack      A
```

final df

```
    ID    Name    Class     A         B       C       D  

0    12    John      A       A
1    13    Mark      A       A
2    14    Tony      B                 B
3    15    Marcus    C                         C
4    16    Phill     D                                D
5    17    Jack      A       A
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
uniq_class = df['Class'].unique().tolist()
# create a diagonal matrix with unique class as value
D = np.diag(uniq_class).tolist()
# map the diagonal matrix dictionary for each class value
temp = dict(zip(uniq_class, D))
# map class values to the temp dictionary
df[uniq_class] = df['Class'].map(temp).tolist()
df
```

Output:

```
   ID    Name Class  A  B  C  D
0  12    John     A  A         
1  13    Mark     A  A         
2  14    Tony     B     B      
3  15  Marcus     C        C   
4  16   Phill     D           D
5  17    Jack     A  A
```

Comment: Hi @LazyCLown 
`temp = dict(zip(v, D))` Here v is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I changed the variable names for readability and missed out on that one. I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

A potentially slow way of doing this would be to define a function and then loop over all possible answers for each item in the original column.

```
#define a function to see if matched value
def new_column_val(row, value, column):
    
    if row[column] == value:
       return value
    else:
      return None

#create the new columns
for class_name in df["class"].unique():

    df[class] = df.apply(new_column_val, args = (class_name, "class")
```

Comment: Hi Philip09 , I'm getting syntax error at for loop

Comment: Yes Philip09, After that also getting syntax error at `for class in`

Comment: Yep, it is a key name. Should change that to class_name as changed.

Comment: Now getting new_column_val() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Okay, add row argument to the function as edited again

Answer (score 1):

you can use get_dummies:

```
mask=pd.get_dummies(df.Class).replace(1,np.nan)
for col in mask.columns:
    mask[col].fillna(col, inplace=True)

final=df.join(mask.replace(0,np.nan))
final
    ID    Name    Class     A         B       C       D  

0    12    John      A       A
1    13    Mark      A       A
2    14    Tony      B                 B
3    15    Marcus    C                         C
4    16    Phill     D                                D
5    17    Jack      A       A
```